# VBA Set Pasted Rows as Range

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

Below is part of the code to copy a range from sheet "Template" and paste to the first blank Row on the Active Sheet. Row 1 is the Header Row.

What I am wanting to do is reference the just pasted rows in order to then `Group` the Rows.

My VBA is poor and I am unsure how to correctly set "PastedRange". How could I achieve this?

```
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long
    Dim PastedRange As Range

    Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set PastedRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With pasteSheet
        '~~> Find the last cell to write to
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) = 0 Then
            LRow = 2
        Else
            LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        End If

        copySheet.Range("2:" & copySheet.Cells(Rows.Count, _ 
        1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        .Rows(LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        PastedRange.Group
    End With
```

Comment: you never use the `PastedRange` and `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` must be  included in `With something` and `End With`. Also, you assign value to `LRow` only. What do you want to paste? Please provide your desired sample and corresponding result

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused as to what you are saying can and can't be done. I have edited the question to include what is being copied. The desired result is that the copied range is pasted onto the active sheet into the first blank row and then the rows that were just pasted, to be grouped.

Comment: No reason to be confused... `Set PastedRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, in the place where it exists, will raise an error. It cannot return anything with that used construction (`.Range(...`), from two points of view: The line returns a row instead of a range, and .Range(...` has a meaning only inside a `With SomeSheet` followed by your code and `End With`.

Comment: I have put ```PastedRange = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)``` and ```PastedRange.Group``` just before End With. Is this the correct way to do it? The grouping hasn't worked.

Comment: It is correct in terms of not returning an error, but your code should calculate the last pasted rows, not the last row. Please, test the code I pasted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will group all pasted rows, except the first one:

```
Sub testGroupRows()
   Dim copySheet As Worksheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet, LRow As Long, csLastRow As Long

    Set copySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    Set pasteSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    With pasteSheet
        '~~> Find the last cell to write to
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.cells) = 0 Then
            LRow = 2
        Else
            LRow = .Range("A" & .rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
        End If
        'if the summary row is not above, set it to be above:
        If .Outline.SummaryRow <> xlSummaryAbove Then .Outline.SummaryRow = xlSummaryAbove
        
        csLastRow = copySheet.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        copySheet.Range("2:" & csLastRow).Copy
        .rows(LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
        
        'group skipping the first copied row:
        .Range(.cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp), .cells(.rows.count, 1).End _
                                       (xlUp).Offset(-(csLastRow - 3), 1)).EntireRow.Group
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @aye cee Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Comment: Thanks, something came up, about to test now :)

Comment: Yes I do need separated groups. The second code is creating separate groups, however the ability to collapse a particular group is lost as the "-" sign is in the row that is hidden. If there is no way to do it and still have the "+/-" It may be better to have the source rows grouped already, as that would work.

Comment: Very strange, previously (just today) I could manually paste a group below another and it would remain separate. Now it is instead extending the group. I wonder if there is a setting that toggles this!?

Comment: @aye cee The "-" sign should be on the first row of the pasted rows. At least, it behaves in this way on my testing workbook. If  not something confidential, can you share yours? And about the manually pasting, I think it could behave as you say only if the first row was (already) empty... This is a general Excel behavior.

Comment: This is excel 2007 so this could be the difference in location?

Comment: @aye cee I don't think so, but I cannot be sure without testing... Theoretically it is only a matter of calculations to determine the first group row.  If you share it, I have another computer with Exel 2007 and I can test it, too.

Comment: I have created a sample worklbook which displays this behaviour. Is there a way to upload a file here?

Comment: I tested a file on 2007 and it behaves differently in terms of the nex aspect: The */- sign is displayed **below** of the bottom row, where the empty row exist.. In all superior versions it is placed on the first row. Please, comment the last code line `.cells(.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-(csLastRow - 1), 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True` and see how it is behaving.

Comment: that works but creates the blank rows between the groups

Comment: @aye cee Now I must leave my office and I do not have at home Excel 2007. I have in mind a solution, but I will show it to you only tomorrow... By!

Comment: @aye cee This was the idea... And then hiding the empty row. But in 2007 the +/- sign is positioned viceversa against all superior versions. And the sign is hide, too...

Comment: I have found this VBA that can change the location of the expand/collapse icon to the top of the group ```ActiveSheet.Outline.SummaryRow = xlAbove```. Also apologies, I have overlooked an important detail - The first row of the pasted cells is not grouped. It stays visible and the rest is collapsed. In this way I think the gaps between the groups won't be an issue. However I am wondering if it is just simpler to group the source rows, except that the last group on the active sheet will always need to be expanded, otherwise data is overwritten.

Comment: @aye cee You did not say anything about how to rows to be grouped and I did not know which is default positioning in 2027. I will adapt the code to work for both cases, grouping all pasted rows, except the first one.

Comment: @aye cee Please, test the above code. It should work in all versions, previously checking the summary row position and place it above if not there. In 2007 the default position is down and in all the following versions is above...

Comment: This works exceptionally well, I thought it might not have been possible. Appreciate  your help very much!